# Custom Camera Roll View in Ionic 4 possible?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I kindly wanted to ask, whether you know a way how it would be possible in Ionic 4 to visualize the camera roll in a custom UI rather than the native view?

If so, could you please link me the plugins with which it would be possible?

(The only thing I find is to show the native camera roll view.)

Warm regards,
Jil

Comment: Anyone an idea? : )

Comment: Does really no one has an idea? : (